# How can I remove "required fields" text from the product page?

Tags: magento

I would like to remove the "required fields" text that appears on the product page right under the "availability:in stock" text when a custom option is used. Can anyone guide?

Comment: It's likely to be in the product template, start there

Comment: do you know the file location?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the text by hide element using css:

`.product-options p.required {display:none;}`

to find out particular template file in magento, use template hint paths. here is the good tutorial to enable this:

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-template-path-hints-magento

Hope this Help !!